# Problem with online class

Tags: academic-life, online-learning, responsibilities

I am a student at my local community college taking pre-nursing classes. My professor for A&P II requires a 360 camera while taking all the tests online on response. I have two small kids who I take care of solely because my husband has to do multiple jobs to keep us alive. we also live in a very small space and I can't have any privacy for tests or a calm environment. Last year fall was my first semester and I had instances where I had to do an exam while feeding the baby or have them play next to me while I do my assignments. I was lucky on instances that something happened while taking tests and had to attend to kids immediately because the professor was understanding and would allow me to finish the exam.

I feel embarrassed about having to explain my living situation to my professor. I have tried to avoid anything that would make me have a virtual meeting and this camera issue make me think if I should stop school for now or reach out if I can get help
What should I do in my situation? Any advice will be appreciated.

NB: I'm a new immigrant and I have no support here not even anyone to help me think through this process.

Answer (score 6):

I can understand your embarrassment, but you may have to overcome it and just ask for an accommodation. A reasonable person should agree.

But many colleges and universities have some sort of office of student assistance for making such requests and passing them on. If that is available it would free you from having to discuss your situation over and over. See if that is a possibility.

And, for what it is worth, I find such requirements to be offensive. Instructors need to find a better way to evaluate students than to intrude on their homes and families. Few students have the capability of setting up a secure testing space and finding others to manage their children, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to ask the college administration if they have a student support service and see if I can get any accommodation regarding my situation

Comment: good luck to you and hugs to your kids.

Comment: I think this is great advice, but you might try asking your professor directly for the accommodation as well.  I also agree that secure exams are problematic in today's environment, but I can't say I've found many profs who have adequately solved this problem (if any).